# How to us Group By in SQL with a JOIN

Tags: sql, select, join, group-by

I am wondering if anyone could help me. I trying to write a query which will group all the order detail lines to each product.

```
    SELECT
      Line.NetAmount, Line.QtyDespatch, Line.QtyOrder,
      Line.Price, Line.Price * Line.QtySent AS 'Value'
      FROM  dbo.orderdetails line

   LEFT JOIN
   (
    SELECT  products.ProductID, products.CompanyID AS StockCompanyID,  
    products.StockCode  FROM dbo.products
   ) 
   Stock ON Line.ProductID = products.ProductID AND products.StockCompanyID = Line.CompanyID    

   WHERE Line.CompanyID = 1
   ORDER BY Stock.StockID ASC
```

The results I am getting are for each order details line individually but I want to group-by the each product id and have (Line.Price * Line.QtySent) as sum for each product and show each product once.

The result I am getting are

```
PID     Net sent   qty      Price  Value
39044   12  0       5       2.4     0
39044   12  0       5       2.4     0
39044   12  0       5       2.4     0
39044   12  0       5       2.4     0
```

But I do not want to get it for each line but a cumulative value for all line by product. Basically cumulative  totals for each product

Comment: Can you show some expected results, your inital query has netamount, qtydespatch and qtyorder which couldn't be in this resultset as we woudlnt' know what line's net amount to use etc..  or are you just after ProductID and TotalPrice in the result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to group by the ProductId and then sum the Line.Price multiplied by the Line.QtySent.  You would want something like this:

```
 SELECT p.ProductID, SUM(Line.Price * Line.QtySent) AS 'Value'
 FROM  dbo.orderdetails line   
 LEFT JOIN dbo.products p ON 
 Line.ProductID = p.ProductID AND p.CompanyID = Line.CompanyID       
 WHERE Line.CompanyID = 1
 GROUP BY p.ProductID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description sounds like this query:

```
SELECT od.ProductId, SUM(od.Price * od.QtySent) as total
FROM  dbo.orderdetails od
GROUP BY od.ProductId;
```